# Cannot understand "multi-syllables" in "Do you do multi-syllables, or are you still working up to that?"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Folks, I am reading one short novel and there is a usage of "multi-syllables" words combination which I cannot really understand.
Here is a piece with a little context:

> He stopped suddenly and turned to face me. ‘I forgot to check . . . did the robot insist that you leave behind your Aide Memoire?’
>   ‘Yes.’
>   ‘Good. It was you I wanted to talk to, Carrie, not some surrogate recording device.’
>   ‘Me?’
>   The pewter mask of his face formed a quizzical expression. ‘Do you do multi-syllables, or are you still working up to that?’
>   ‘Er . . .’

Could you explain the meaning of "do multi-syllables" here?

Comment: Maybe a reference to using/ability to use difficult words (words with multiple syllables)?

Comment: Carrie is what we disparagingly refer to as "monosyllabic."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words of more than one syllable. The question is rather sarcastic.

> Are you really stupid? Do I need to speak only using simple words, words with just one syllable?

Carrie is appearing to be slow to understand by saying

> Me?

when I suspect actually she is surprised that someone is interested in what she has to say.